# Server for displaying pictures in web browser

Tags: c#, server

What I am trying to do is send a picture from the server to the client (web browser). So when I open the link in the browser, for example https://localhost:8080/geoserver/ (I set the port to 8080 at the beginning) it will display the message "hello world" which is fine but now I am trying to send image with the StreamWriter and all I got was some text like `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and there was no picture displayed in the browser. Im working with c# console application.

My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpListener listen = new HttpListener();
    string url = "http://localhost";
    string port = "";
    Console.Write("Nastavite port:");
    port = Console.ReadLine();
    url = url + ":" + port + "/geoserver/";
    listen.Prefixes.Add(url);
    listen.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cakam...");
        HttpListenerContext kontekst = listen.GetContext();

        string msg = "hello world";

        kontekst.Response.ContentLength64 = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(msg);
        kontekst.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

        using(Stream stream = kontekst.Response.OutputStream)
        {
            using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(msg);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sporočilo poslano");
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your image ?

Comment: I load it with Image i = Image.FromFile("image.jpg"); and it is stored in the same folder as the server.

Comment: Can you post that code which you are trying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, by converting the image to base64 and display it in a html `img` tag.
1) Use the `System.Drawing` library to get the picture as a byte array

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("test-img.jpg");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] imgBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

2) After you need to convert it to a base64 string

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);
```

3) Then you create the html response text

```
string html = $"<html><img src=\"data: image / png; base64, {base64} \"></html>";
```

4) Now you can write this text to the output stream

```
Stream stream = kontekst.Response.OutputStream;
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.WriteLine(html);
```

So the full working code looks like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpListener listen = new HttpListener();
    string url = "http://localhost";
    string port = "";
    Console.Write("Nastavite port:");
    port = Console.ReadLine();
    url = url + ":" + port + "/geoserver/";
    listen.Prefixes.Add(url);
    listen.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cakam...");
        HttpListenerContext kontekst = listen.GetContext();

        kontekst.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

        using (Stream stream = kontekst.Response.OutputStream)
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile("test-img.jpg"))
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            writer.WriteLine($"<html><img src=\"data: image / png; base64, {base64} \"></html>");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sporočilo poslano");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimal changes required to make your code work is to use the Save method to write the image to the stream, instead of `Writer.Write()`, which will call the `ToString()` of the object, (if it's not already a character array) resulting in sending the class name that you experienced.

```
//Can't set the response length upfront, if you really need to set it you need to 
//calculate it from the size of the image.
//kontekst.Response.ContentLength64 = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(msg);
//Most browsers figure it out without this, but good practice to set the type:
kontekst.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";
kontekst.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
var img = Image.FromFile(@"some.bmp");
using (Stream stream = kontekst.Response.OutputStream)
{
    img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

I would also consider changing some other things:

1. Instead of `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, use `System.Drawing.Image` as I did if you don't need to edit the image on the server. Or even better, if you don't need to treat it as an image on the server side, just read it in with a `FileStream` and write it out to the Output stream.
2. Do you really want to implement your on server and deal with the low level HttpContext / listeners? Maybe you could use ASP.Net Core with Kestrel.